# What are the class skills for animals?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, animals, skills

I'm working on an anthropomorphic giant octopus character (yes that's a real race, you can find it in Savage Species and it's awesome). From the two racial hit dice I get skill points equal to (2+Int)x5, but I can't figure out what the heck are class skills for animals (anthropomorphic animals use the same class skills as their regular animal counterparts). I have a vague memory that any skill listed in their entry is a class skill for them, but haven't found anything to back that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Monster Manual* on [Skills](http://dndsrd.net/monsters.html#skills) says, "All listed skills [in a monster's stat block] are class skills, unless the creature has a character class (noted in the entry)" (7).

Thus an anthropomorphic giant octopus (*Savage Species* 216) has the class skills Escape Artist, Hide, Listen, Spot, and Swim, the same class skills as a [giant octopus](http://dndsrd.net/monstersAnimal.html#giant-octopus) (*MM* 276-7).

Keep in mind that an anthropomorphic giant octopus's ECL 2 is rarely worth it, despite the awesomeness of an anthropomorphic giant octopus PC.

Comment: Anthropomorphic giant octopodes only have an ECL of 2 (they got hit harder by the conversion, losing large size), which is much more viable.

Comment: @PoeticallyPsychotic My apologies. I had overlooked the word *giant*.

Comment: Don't sweat it, I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Fun with multi weapon fighting?

Comment: @nijineko Unfortunately, I think an anthropomorphic giant octopus is just, like, a humanlike dude with octopusish features rather than, for instance, an 8-tentacled mind flayer on steroids. I think you'd want to play an actual *awakened* octopus, but that's ECL 5 (*Dragon* #293 54), *and* that description specifically says, "An awakened octopus still can't use more than 2 weapons" (53), *and* it repeats that info on the chart entry in case the reader missed it. The ECL 15 *awakened* giant squid, however, is fine, though, but good luck with that! `:-)`

Comment: I think I'll stick with a warshaper then, despite the ambiguity.

Comment: And shades of TMNT! ^^

Comment: @nijineko, actually anthropomorphic octopodes (giant or otherwise) do have six tentacles (two become legs), and can presumably use them to wield multiple weapons. I went the Totemist route instead, using Heart of Fire to give all of them bonus damage.

Answer (score 1):

### All skills listed in an entry are class skills

The "[Reading the Monster Entries](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/intro.htm#skills)" section of the SRD states (emphasis mine):

> **Skills**
>
> This line gives the creature’s skills, along with each skill’s modifier (including adjustments for ability scores, armor check penalties, and any bonuses from feats or racial traits). *All listed skills are class skills, unless the creature has a character class (noted in the entry)*. A creature’s type and Intelligence score determine the number of skill points it has.

Racial/"type" hit dice don't have class skill lists. Any skill taken with those points is considered a class skill for those HD and grants a full rank.

This is one of those things that notably changed in Pathfinder, where the skill/class skill system works a bit differently and "type" HD *do* have an associated "class" skill list (as can be seen on [this table](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/)).